# database design for react native application with in app purchase

Tags: sql, react-native, database-design, nosql, in-app-purchase

I want to design database schemas for react native applications that have in app purchase and free with ads.  Can you help me or give me a link to a document or book about that issue?  I'm so grateful

I also tried designing the above database, but I hope to have a standard database, for SQL or nosql